# Is buying a lens with image stabilization (IS) worth the money?

Tags: lens, canon

I have been saving up to buy a Canon 70-200 mm f/2.8 IS lens and was wondering if the IS is worth the extra $ or can I buy a lens without it, and spend the extra $ on a extra lens like the 17-40mm?

Comment: It's not really the question you asked, but the Canon 70-200/2.8 without the IS is an older-generation lens. While that series has always been an excellent performer, I'm told that the II version is much-improved, so there's a second reason to wait to buy the IS version. If it were me looking to save money, I'd instead be looking at the 70-200/4, on the grounds that I don't need f/2.8, and would like to save the weight. Certainly at the wide end in the 17-40 you're looking at, f/2.8 is questionable, but it's not so easy with a lens so perfectly suited to portraiture and such. Good luck!

Comment: Oh, and if the alternative to the Canon lens was one of the third-party 70-200/2.8s, I'd say go for the Canon, if you can. There really is a performance difference, particularly in things like AF speed, durability, etc. I had the Tokina 70-200/2/.8 for a time, and have a similar-class Sigma prime still, and they really are not in the same class as the Canon lens, in terms of lens body features. Optically, maybe close, but that only helps *after* focus is achieved, which is simply faster and easier with the Canon.

Comment: @WarrenYoung Might want to specify with the 70-400/4L whether you mean the [newer IS](http://www.canon.com/c-museum/en/product/ef391.html) or [older non-IS version](http://www.canon.com/c-museum/en/product/ef356.html). :)